# Teradata equivalent of MySQL's USING

Tags: mysql, join, using, teradata

My question is quite similar to this one, but in Teradata:

[SQL Server equivalent of MySQL's USING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859277/sql-server-equivalent-of-mysqls-using)

Is there any equivalent shortcut to this query?

```
SELECT * 
  FROM t1 
  JOIN t2 
    ON (t1.column = t2.column)
```

Comment: Usually teradata doesnt check for same named columns in the tables when doing a join. I dont think this is supported. You can use the same ON condition to comply to the standards.

Answer (score 1):

No. The closest thing you can do with a natural join is:

```
SELECT
FROM T1, T2
WHERE t1.column = t2.column;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's ANSI JOIN syntax. For example:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM T1
   INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.column = T2.column
;
```

For a multiple column join criteria, do the following:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM T1
   INNER JOIN T2 ON T2.column1 = T1.column1
      AND T2.column2 = T1.column2
   LEFT OUTER JOIN T3 ON T3.column1 = T2.column1 
;
```

Detailed, comprehensive information with examples is available in Chapter 2 of [Teradata® RDBMS SQL Reference - Volume 6 Data Manipulation Statements](http://www.info.teradata.com/edownload.cfm?itemid=102320040).

Comment: Whoops. Missed the word "shortcut" in the original question RE USING. Rephrased, the answer is "NO". ;)

Answer (score 0):

If Teradata supports NATURAL JOINs, then you're set. In MySQL, NATURAL JOINs are INNER JOINs with a USING clause. Also, you can add a LEFT|RIGHT and OUTER clauses to the NATURAL clause to further specify how you want the JOIN made.

Check the documentation of Teradata, hopefully it should support it.